# Open URL from within a javascript-based Adobe AIR app

Tags: javascript, air

I've got an adobe AIR application that is written entirely in HTML/Javascript (no Flash).  It's mostly self-contained but there's a single link that is meant to open a url in the user's default browser.  Instead, it opens it in a separate AIR browser window.  How can I go about forcing AIR to open the link in the user's default browser?

In looking around, I've seen reference to this method:

```
 air.navigateToURL
```

(http://livedocs.adobe.com/labs/air/1/jslr/flash/net/navigateToURL.html)

Which I've tried:

```
 navigateToUrl: function(url) {
    var request = new air.URLRequest(url);
try {            
        air.navigateToURL(request);
        return true;
    }
    catch (e) {
        return false;
    }       
 },

 ....

 <a href="#" onclick="Utilities.navigateToUrl('http://google.com')">Click here</a>
 ....
```

But it has no effect (no response from AIR and no browser opened).

Comment: If I recall correctly, the sample program for HTML/CSS/JS that comes with AIR opens a browser window. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove this line, it should work:

```
request.data = variables;
```

`variables` doesn't look like it's defined in the scope of the `navigateToUrl` function.

Comment: Thanks.  That made it into my demo code but isn't in the executing code.  But thanks for the edit.  I've updated the question.

Comment: I've copy/pasted the code that you have, and it works for me.  Are there no messages in the AIR console?

Comment: Really?  Yeah, no messages.   I guess there's something else going on with my code.  Thanks for taking the time to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

(ignore my previous edit :P )

```
onclick = function(){
  air.navigateToURL( new air.URLRequest('http://google.com') );
}
```

I hope that works for you. Worked for me.